# Algorithm to calculate total unique permutations of set of lists that contain some items

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

Consider a config file like this:

```
A = <some value> 
B = <some value>
C = <some value>
```

Where each option A/B/C can take up any value X which belongs to a list L. The size of this list L is fixed and known before hand. Note that there can be any number of entries in the config file - i.e. there can be a D, E, F .. and so on ..

Thus, as an example,

```
A = <any value from list {1,2,3,4}>
B = <any value from list {5, 10, 15}> 
C = <any value from list {10,20,30,40,50}>
```

What is an algorithm to generate each permutation of config file possible (without making duplicates)?

Which means creating all possible config files like -

```
A=1
B=5
C=10

A=1
B=5
C=20

A=1
B=5
C=30

.
.
.

And so on
```

I know this might not exactly qualify as a "programming question" and rather as a "algorithm one", but I have seen questions from [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) and such being asked (and appreciated well) here. Still I apologise if this comes out to be off topic or something.

Comment: This is not a permutation, but a product. `itertools.product(A,B,C)` would produce exactly what you want.

Comment: @mata Where A,B,C is the list of possible values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  You should read up on the standard lib `itertools` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

```
import itertools

l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [5,10,15]
l3 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

for a, b, c in itertools.product(l1, l2, l3):
    print a,b,c
```

As the method signature of `itertools.product` is: `(*iterables[,repeat])`

You handle a variable number of lists easily by just doing:

```
lists = get_my_lists() # whatever
itertools.product(*lists)
```

Comment: This is a library not an algorithm.

Comment: The algorithm is "calculate the `product`".  Python just happens to ship with a performant standard implementation of this `algorithm`.

Comment: @MikeSteder Is it possible to pass a list that contains the lists instea of the individual lists themselves to that product function?

Comment: @Wildling - sure, just use argument unpaking: `L = [l1, l2, ...]` and then `itertools.product(*L)`

Answer (score 1):

Or by hand:

```
[(x,y,z) for x in l1 for y in l2 for z in l3] ...
```